# Current values of the options for StyleData cell

Tags: stylesheet

In a style sheet there is this definition:

```
Cell[
  StyleData["InputInert"], 
    CellFrame -> {{5, 1}, {1, 1}}, 
    CellMargins -> {{66, 10}, {5, 10}}, 
    CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[0, 0.501961, 0.752941], 
    MenuSortingValue -> 10000
]
```

but

```
CurrentValue[
  Cell[
    StyleData["InputInert"]
  ],#
 ]& /@ {"CellFrame","CellMargins","CellFrameColor"}
```

returns for some options the corresponding value  (`CellMargins`), whereas for some others a different one (`CellFrame` or `CellFrameColor`):

```
{True,{{66,10},{5,10}},GrayLevel[0.85]}
```

Please, can you explain why ?

Comment: Where did you get that `CurrentValue` with `StyleData` syntax from?

Comment: I'm sorry, it comes from am ancient scratchpad notebook and I have no way to trace back its sources. But most likely it's from this community or some improvisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the style to the notebook's stylesheet and then tweak your command to this:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "InputInert", #}] & /@ {CellFrame, 
      CellMargins, CellFrameColor}
```

You'll get the right response:

[image]